# Is there an algorithm for determining the smallest set of solvable linear equations

Tags: algorithm, math

I have a set of N (N is very large) linear equations with W variables.

For efficiency sake, I need to find the smallest number of linear equations that are solvable (have a unique solution).  It can be assumed that a set of X equations containing Y variables has a unique solution when X == Y.

For example, if I have the following as input:

```
2a = b - c
a = 0.5b
b = 2 + a
```

I want to return the equation set:

```
a = 0.5b
b = 2 + a
```

Currently, I have an implementation that uses some heuristics.  I create a matrix, columns are variables and rows are equations.  I search the matrix to find a set of fully connected equations, and then one-by-one try removing equations to see if the remaining set of equations is still solvable, if it is continue, if not, return the set of equations.

Is there a known algorithm for this, and am I trying got reinvent the wheel?
Does anyone have input on how to better approach this?

Thanks.

Comment: By "solvable" do you mean "has a unique solution" or "has a solution"?  Technically "solvable" means "has a solution", and each one of your equations alone has a solution, so the smallest number is 1.

Comment: I have a suspicion you're talking about [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) on a system of equations.

Comment: Are you dealing with *linear* equations only? Why would you only solve two equations in your case, although `a=2, b=4, c=0` would solve all three, and without the first you don't know wnything about `c`? I agree with @beaker in that one would likely use Gaussian elimination to deal with this. The numerics of that can be tricky, though.

Comment: By "solvable" I mean "has a unique solution".  Will edit for clarity.

Comment: All equations can be assumed to be linear.  Gaussian elimination does not help.  Gaussian elimination operates on all equations, I would like to identify a solvable subset of equations, then perform something like gaussian elimination on it.

Comment: There are algorithms for that. They are not particularly easy to understand or implement. Start by reading [this presentation](http://graal.ens-lyon.fr/~bucar/CR07/lecture-matching.pdf), you will get some concepts and terminology.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is "yes", there are known algorithms. For example, you could add a single equation and then compute the rank of the matrix. Then add the next equation and compute the rank. If it hasn't gone up that new equation isn't helping any and you can get rid of it. Once the rank == the number of variables you have a unique solution and you're done. There are libraries (e.g. [Colt](https://dst.lbl.gov/ACSSoftware/colt/), [JAMA](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/), [la4j](http://la4j.org/), etc.) that will do this for you.

Longer answer is that this is surprisingly difficult to do correctly, especially if your matrix gets big. You end up with lots of numerical stability issues and so on. I'm not a numerical linear algebra expert but I know enough to know there are dragons here if you're not careful. Having said that, if your matrices are small and "well conditioned" (the rows/columns aren't almost parallel) then you should be in good shape. It depends on your application.

Comment: This by no means finds *the smallest* solvable set.

Comment: @n.m. really? Assuming that there is in fact a solution, the solution will lie in the column space for the matrix. I believe the above will find a minimal basis for that column space. Since dimension of row-space == dimension of column-space doesn't this guarantee you a minimal set of equations? Am I missing something? Granted, if there is no solution the above is broken, but I don't think that's the issue you're pointing out.

Comment: Take this set of equations: x1+x2=a1; x2+x3=a2; x3+x4 = a3; ...; x99+x100 = a99; x1-x3=a100; What does your algorithm find if you add equations in this order? The ideal algorithm should find the set that consists of the first, second, and last equations.

Comment: @n.m. Interesting. The solution you propose (1st, 2nd and last) will indeed have a unique solution but it won't be a "complete" solution as the values for x4, x5, x6, ..., x100 will be unknown. I don't have a formal way of stating this but it's something like "a unique but incomplete" solution or something. Not sure if the solution you propose would be a valid solution for the OP or not. If so, then yes, my solution won't find the minimal set. But if you also want a solution that correctly assigns values to **all** the variables then I think what I've proposed works. Does that sound right?

Comment: That's the idea. You solve a small subset first, eliminate its variables from the rest of the equations, find another small solvable subset, repeat. It should be faster than usual methods if your matrix is huge and sparse. In the example above, you can solve the entire system extremely quickly. Once you have eliminated x1, x2 and x3, x3+x4 is immediately solvable; then x4+x5, etc. There are in fact methods based on this.

Comment: This method does not work, I have attempted to implement it.  Take for example:  { a=b , a = c, ... , c = 2b}  If I start with a=b.  I have 1 equation and 2 unknowns or a rank 1 (2-1) matrix.  Then add the equation a=c, I have 2 eqn's and 3 unknowns still a rank 1 (3-2) matrix.  However, it is clear both equations are required for the solution.

Comment: @n.m. "The ideal algorithm should find the set that consists of the first, second, and last equations."  This is correct.

Comment: @Chris in my solution you don't include the "answer" part of the matrix. You start with the classic `Ax = b` type setup where `A` is the matrix from the left of the `=` and `b` is the vector of stuff after the `=`. The solution refers to just the matrix `A`.In your example start with `a = b` which means the matrix `A` is just a 1x1 matrix. You then try to add `a = c` and get a 2x1 matrix and find that won't help (note again that my example assumes there is a solution so this can't help) so you'd drop that equation. You then try `c = 2b` which gives you a 2x2 rank-2 matrix so you keep that.

Comment: @Chris yes, if solutions that don't assign values to all variables are acceptable then my solution won't find the smallest subset.

Comment: @Chris, to clarify, in my solution you start with the classic `Ax = b` type setup where `A` is the matrix from the left of the `=` and `b` is a vector of **constants**, the stuff after the `=`. If you have variables on the right of the `=` you have to rearrange terms so there are no variables on the right (just move 'em to the other side and swap the sign). The solution refers to just the matrix `A`. So for your example your first equation gives `[[1, -1]]` as the matrix. After the 2nd you have `[[1, -1, 0][1, 0, -1]]`, etc.This the standard linear algebra setup.

Comment: @Oliver Dain Thanks, however, I still don't see how this method can work.  For example: considering a=b and a=c giving   [[1, -1, 0][1, 0, -1]]  there is no improvement to the matrix's rank. considering a=b and c=2b giving  [[1, -1, 0][0, -2, 1]]  there is also no improvement to the matrix's rank. Using your algorithm, I would discard both equations as neither, when considered alone, neither equation reduces the degrees of freedom of the first equation.  However, it is apparent that togeather they provide a solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133845/discussion-between-chris-and-oliver-dain).